# How to Import Code from extracted JAR in redhat developer studio

Tags: java

Can anyone let me know how to get rid of the error "Selection doesn't contain main method" in redhat developer studio.
I have exported the code from a JAR file using 'JDGUI' tool. Then I created a normal java project and added the extracted code to src folder. No errors found. When I try to run , I got "Selection doesn't contain main method" error popup.
So I did link the src folder in build configuration as suggested. If I did so my folder structure itself got mess up and shows multiple errors inside project.

Please suggest solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Any Java application to run need a public static void main method. Do you have it in your extracted code? Your Java should know where to start from.

Comment: Yeah. I have the main method and i linked the file to src folder too. But it doesnt help me to run my code.